# WinRT XAML toolkit lineseries chart displays wrong results

Tags: vb.net, xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I have a UWP app to control a kiln.I represent the temperature of the kiln over time in a Linegraph from the WinRT XAML Toolkit. To display I use this XAML:

```
<Charting:Chart x:Name="MyLineSeriesChart" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.082,0.454" Width="480" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Charting:Chart.Axes >
        <Charting:DateTimeAxis AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource HorizontalLabelStyle}" Orientation="X"/>
    </Charting:Chart.Axes>
    <Charting:LineSeries Name="LineChart" Title="Temp" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" Margin="0,-38,-75,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
        <!--     <Charting:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
            <Charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="True" Title="Temp"/>
        </Charting:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>-->
        <Charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
            <Style TargetType="Charting:LineDataPoint">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </Charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
    </Charting:LineSeries>
</Charting:Chart>
```

You see a commented out part. I used that before. It worked OK but I wanted a different interval. In XAML you cannot set an interval because of the not nullable problem.
So I set the interval in VB code:

```
    DirectCast(MyLineSeriesChart.Series(0), LineSeries).DependentRangeAxis = New LinearAxis() With {
        .Title = "Temp",
        .Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y,
        .Minimum = 0,
        .Maximum = 1000,
        .Interval = 100,
        .ShowGridLines = True
    }
```

But the result is worse:
[image: Linegraph]

The temperature starts at 15 C up to about 1.000 C. But as you can see the graph shows very different figures. The actual temps in the graph's time were 15 to 200 C.

I pull my hair out as to why?

Comment: Could you share a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Include code to generate the data, removing the dependency on your current view model.

Answer (score 0):

I just test your XAML code snippet, my graph was also not placed properly. So, I just removed following from the code and its just perfect

```
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
<Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
```

Hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Tried this, but I see no difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat of an old post, I realize, but wanted to briefly provide some information in case someone runs into this too and is having the same issues.
I had the same problem as described above (values were not were they were 'meant' to be on the Y-axis) but upon stepping through the code, I found that the margin property (set in the above code to Margin="0,-38,-75,0") was causing the shift. 
Setting it to  Margin="0,0,-75,0" resolved the issue for me...
the -75 value is somewhat arbitrary based on what data is being shown.